# Embed a PDF with the url having a variable

Tags: object, embed, var

I'm new to html, I am trying to open a PDF  using a embed object but my issue is the url has a variable in the url like"http://server.com/files/" +var+ ".PDF" but adding it like that to the src of the embed doesn't work, I can save it as a variable and do a on click but it doesn't embed, it just asks to save.

Comment: my .js :  var partnumber = prompt("PARTNUMBER", "");
   if (partnumber!= null) {
     document.getElementById("partNumber").value = partnumber;
 }




function redirectTo(){
var objectlink="http://my server.com/File/Index/" +partnumber+ ".pdf"

window.location.href= objectlink

}

Comment: html:                                                                                                                       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TITLE</title>


  </head>
  <body>











<input type="button" value="pdf viewer" onclick="redirectTo()">




<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>